# How to execute laravel job (queue)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

developers, I have a problem. My queue not working or i just not understand how it's works. I create a command which should add a new queue job. Driver for Queue is - database. After executing my command i see a new row in table 'jobs'. After that I try to do "php artisan queue:work" - but nothing happens.

Help me please, how can I execute this job?

Comment: Have you checked your logs for any possible errors?

Comment: I also tried to execute queue:listen - no results.

Answer (score 13):

[From the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#running-the-queue-listener) : [**Daemon Queue Listener**] The `queue:work` artisan command includes a `--daemon` option for forcing the queue worker to continue processing jobs without ever re-booting the framework. This results in a significant reduction of CPU usage when compared to the queue:listen command:

To start a queue worker in daemon mode, use the `--daemon` flag:

```
php artisan queue:work connection --daemon
```

However if you don't have multiple connections remove connection and execute it without connection :

```
php artisan queue:work --daemon
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try

`php artisan queue:listen`

instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are times when your queue jobs won't run. For deployment if you are using redis queue driver, if not you can follow this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis) to install and configure redis and after which you should create a table for failed jobs using
`php artisan queue:failed-table`
`php artisan migrate` and then use `php artisan queue:work redis --tries=3 --backoff=3` to retry every failed jobs 3 times after 3 seconds of failure.

Answer (score 0):

To delay the next retry just add `--delay=[NUM_OF_SECONDS]` to your command.

For example, to wait 30 seconds to retry after failing just

```
run: php artisan queue:work tries=3 --delay=30
```

OR

```
php artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=3 --sleep=5 --delay=10
```